# Why call from makefile returns empty result while same call from console does not?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, makefile

I want to do shortcut with Makefile to delete docker **image** after i rebuild one of the services with `docker-compose up --build`, because dangling images are created with every rebuild.

My solution get image_id of stoped container and `docker rmi` it. As part if this a have to obtain image id, which i do like this:

```bash
export CONTAINER=name_1
docker container inspect --format='{{.Image}}' $CONTAINER
# > sha256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

But i get empty ouput from it if i call with makefile:

./Makefile

```
CONTAINER=name_1
cmd:
    echo $(docker container inspect --format='{{.Image}}' $CONTAINER)
```

```bash
cmd
# > echo
```

I do not understard what is the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
echo $(docker container inspect --format='{{.Image}}' $CONTAINER)
```

does not run `docker`.  `$` is special to make and it introduces a make variable, so you are expanding a very oddly-named (and empty) variable.  You have to escape all `$` as `$$` in your recipe to hide it from make.

Also, makefile variable references that are >1 character long must be enclosed in either `()` or `{}` (they are equivalent):

```
echo $$(docker container inspect --format='{{.Image}}' ${CONTAINER})
```

Comment: yes it helps. However why than works "echo $(docker container inspect --format='{{.Image}}' $CONTAINER)" in bash-console it return scorrect output, not empty string

Comment: @Archirk when you run that command you are using `$(...)` which tells bash: run this command and put the output here. However, when you put the same command in Makefile, the first to interpret it is Make, which has its own variable expansions and when it reads the line it searches for a variable called "docker container inspect..." inside the Makefile itself and it actually doesn't run the command. What $$ makes is escape the $ character to Make so it doesn't recognize it as a variable expansion and passes the whole line to bash with a single $.

Comment: The way make works is it takes the recipe you've provided, it expands the make variables in the recipe, then it gives the resulting string to the shell to run.  When you run it from a bash prompt you are not running it through make so make doesn't expand any variables.  When make expands variables it doesn't know which things you wanted it to expand and which you didn't: it just expands everything.  So if there are things you DON'T want it to expand (`$` you want the shell to see, not make) you have to escape them as `$$`.